# Can I use same DockerFile for Remote development and production build in VS Code?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I am running my node app in a container using VS Code Remote. Generally, I created `.devcontainer\devcontainer.json` and `.devcontainer\DockerFile` and it starts container on it's own and everything work just fine.

Now when I try to move to production that uses AWS ECR and ECS I try to build image. When I build it through the terminal I can error because of `COPY . .` copy content of `.devcontainer` the folder where DockerFile exists. If I change to `COPY .. .` I have another error that COPY cannot copy the parent folder.

I try to run the command Rebuild Container in VS Code menu but that image woks only in VS Code and when I upload it fails to run.

So, now I move DockerFile to root, run docker build command then move that file back and upload that image to ECR registry.

What do I miss here? I have very simple node file

```
FROM node:12-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV dev

RUN mkdir /home/node/app \
    && apk add git

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY . .

VOLUME ["/var/log/icod"]

CMD ["node", "/home/node/app/src/index.js"]
```